# How to create meaningful REST response messages?

Tags: rest, get, jersey

I have created a REST service and I was wondering what the best practice was for sending meaningful messages to a GET request. Basically my GET request returns a specific object, something like this;

```
@GET
@Path("/examsple")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<SomeObject> retrieveSomeObjs() {

    List<SomeObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        result = ... Get SomeObjects ...;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ... Deal with exception ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

That works great except when there is an error the response just sends back an empty List! What would be more useful would be a message that explains what the problem is. However I cant send back a String message because the return type is List!

My current solution is to change the return type to a Map and then I can return the object wrapped in the Map along with any messages. However its a little messy on the client side and I was wondering if there was either an inbuilt solution or an 'accepted' solution for this.

Comment: What kind of error can occur? Is something on the server broken? Did the client provide bad input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the client has made an error then use [HTTP Response codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). If an item is not found then your response would be a `404 Not Found`. If the user does not have permissions to access an object then return a `403 Forbidden`. Currently you are responding with a `200 OK` saying everything is OK when it's not.

If it's an error at the server side you don't really want to be sending that information to your clients. Catch the error on the server and do something meaningful with it (like log it) so you can change the code so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: +1 for "you are responding with a 200 OK saying everything is OK when it's not."

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't realise that Response had the capacity to wrap the objects. For some reason I thought it could only return a status.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an HTTP error status code in the header and a JSON response body with an object describing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned some common error codes for GET requests include:

- **`301 Moved Permanently`** - If the resource has been moved
- **`400 Bad Request`** - If the client request is unaccaptable, i.e. if the client sends none-sense parameters in the request
- **`401 Unauthorized`** - If the client did not provide any valid credentials
- **`403 Forbidden`** - If the client is authorized but not allowed to perform the request (you can also return a 404 in this case to conceal that this resource exists at all)
- **`404 Not Found`** - If the requested resource could not be found

I usually create a POJO to represent these error messages and then return it using a Jersey `Response` object.

For example the error object could look like this:

```
public class ApiError {

    private String status;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private String developerMessage;

    // Getters and Setters here

}
```

To return it you can do the following (i.e. in your catch block or your custom ExceptionMapper):

```
ApiError error = new ApiError("409", "409-1", message, developerMessage);
return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(error).build();
```

This way you can provide nicely formatted JSON/XML error messages containing custom error codes and further information for the developer. The error entities will get serialized according to your `@Produces` annotation.